# Run xmlaccess command locally against remote portal server

Tags: websphere-portal

I'm trying to run xmlaccess from my computer and websphere portal server is installed on different machine connected over lan with mine. I did all the configuration of adding jar files on my computer and then running the xmlaccess command with required parameters. but i keeps on giving the same output and doesn't create an output file.I have copied all the jar files as given on ibm knowledge centre.

this is command i give and the output i get everytime, when running the same command on the machine where websphere is installed, it creates the output file and works all fine

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\deployment>xmlaccess -in C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\deploymen
t\ExportAllPortlets.xml -url http://172.16.100.227:10039/wps/config -out Exporte
dWebModules.xml -user ****** -password ******
Licensed Materials - Property of IBM, 5724-E76, 5724-E77, 5724-I29 and 5655-Y16,
 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2001, 2014 - All Rights reserved. US Government Users R
estricted Rights - Use, duplication or disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule
 Contract with IBM Corp.
EJPXB0001I: Command line parameters:
         -in <xml input file>
        [-user <user name>]
                Will be queried over the console, if omitted
        [-password <password>]
                Will be queried over the console, if omitted
        [-useEncryptedCredentials <file>]
                Retrieve user name and password from properties file. Update fil
e with encrypted password.
        [-noUpdateProperties]
                Do not save encrypted password back to properties file.
        [-out <output file>]
                default: write to stdout
        [-url <portal config URL>]
                default: http://localhost/wps/config
        [-attempts <max. connection attempts>]
                default: 1 attempt, no retries
        [-truststore <file name of the trust store for HTTPS>]
                default: $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts
        [-trustpwd <password for the trust store for HTTPS>]
                default: <empty>
        [-trusttype <file type of the trust store for HTTPS>]
                default: jks
        [-keystore <file name of the key store for HTTPS>]
                default: $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts
        [-keypwd <password for the key store for HTTPS>]
                default: <empty>
        [-keytype <file type of the key store for HTTPS>]
                default: jks
        [-credentialexport]
                enables export and import of credential secrets
        [-protocol <protocol>]
                selects the protocol (if portal config URL
                specified https:, otherwise this parameter is ignored).
                default: SSL
        [-encryptionPassphrase <passphrase>]
                passphrase for credential encryption and decryption
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try putting it in a non virtualized directory, like c:\xmlaccess instead of on the desktop.

create a folder in that directory called plugins
Please these jars in there
 bootstrap.jar, com.ibm.ffdc.jar, com.ibm.ws.emf.jar, com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar, j2ee.jar, org.eclipse.emf.common.jar,  org.eclipse.emf.ecore.jar, wp.base.jar, wp.engine.impl.jar, wp.utilities.streams.jar,wp.xml.client.jar

I was using a 1.8 jdk
Then set up your bat file like this

```
@echo off
set WAS_HOME=C:\xmlacess\plugins

set cpath=%WAS_HOME%\com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar
set cpath=%cpath%;%WAS_HOME%\bootstrap.jar
set cpath=%cpath%;%WAS_HOME%\com.ibm.ws.emf.jar
set cpath=%cpath%;%WAS_HOME%\org.eclipse.emf.ecore.jar
set cpath=%cpath%;%WAS_HOME%\org.eclipse.emf.common.jar

%JAVA% -classpath c:\xmlaccess\plugins\wp.xml.client.jar;%WAS_HOME%\wp.base.jar;%WAS_HOME%\wp.engine.impl.jar;%WAS_HOME%\wp.utilities.streams.jar;%WAS_HOME%\j2ee.jar;%WAS_HOME%\com.ibm.ffdc.jar;%cpath% com.ibm.wps.xmlaccess.XmlAccess %*
```

Comment: I'm using jre version 6, also, tried putting it on C drive, no success yet  @Crosstalk22

Comment: so I am using a JRE 8, and I set up my bat file like this  @echo off
set WAS_HOME=C:\xmlacess\plugins

set cpath=%WAS_HOME%\com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar
set cpath=%cpath%;%WAS_HOME%\bootstrap.jar
set cpath=%cpath%;%WAS_HOME%\com.ibm.ws.emf.jar
set cpath=%cpath%;%WAS_HOME%\org.eclipse.emf.ecore.jar
set cpath=%cpath%;%WAS_HOME%\org.eclipse.emf.common.jar

%JAVA% -classpath c:\xmlaccess\plugins\wp.xml.client.jar;%WAS_HOME%\wp.base.jar;%WAS_HOME%\wp.engine.impl.jar;%WAS_HOME%\wp.utilities.streams.jar;%WAS_HOME%\j2ee.jar;%WAS_HOME%\com.ibm.ffdc.jar;%cpath% com.ibm.wps.xmlaccess.XmlAccess %*

Comment: I put the following jars in the plugins directory bootstrap.jar
 com.ibm.ffdc.jar
com.ibm.ws.emf.jar
com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar
j2ee.jar
org.eclipse.emf.common.jar
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.jar
wp.base.jar
wp.engine.impl.jar
 wp.utilities.streams.jar
 wp.xml.client.jar

Comment: is there any way to deploy a war file on portal server which is installed on linux from windows machine ?

Comment: you mean like over the wire?  not really, you could map from the linux machine to a share on the windows machine and pull from there, but if you want it to all go over the wire not really, it expects them to be mapable from the server, you could script it to ftp it to the linux server and then point to the correct location in xmlaccess.  Other options are to use admin console, or create a servlet to create your own

Comment: it worked for me.. i mounted my drive where the war files are located on linux machine, and gave that path in my deploy portlet file.. it works fine..
Thanks for the support..!